# Select throws an ORA-01858 exception

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

With the following query, the Oracle exception is thrown.
However, I cant see why.  Can anyone shed some light?

```
select visit_id, to_date(response, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as convertedDate from 
(
select *
from dat_results_ext
where item_name = 'CALLBACKDATE'
)
where to_date(response, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  > sysdate
```

I understand the exception to be mean that its trying to convert the 'response' field, but it is meeting a non-numeric.  Problem is the row that it should bring back has everything in the right format.

The 'response' field is a varchar field, but all the rows coming back with the 'item_name = 'CALLBACKDATE' clause are all of the correct format.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's because some `response` value is not convertible to a date. Can you show us some of its contents?

Comment: The sub query returns one row with a response of '28/09/2012'.  There are some rows in the dat_results_ext table with different formats, but they are not brought back by the query because of the 'where item_name='CALLBACKDATE'' clause.

Comment: There must be some values of response which is not matching the conditions .

Comment: never store dates in a varchar field, this is asking for trouble.

Comment: The subquery (select * from dat_results_ext..) only returns 1 row with a response of '28/09/2012'... there is no other row returned, so its hard to see how it would be meeting any different value to throw this exception

Comment: Sounds like predicate pushing - the date check being pushed up into the inline view. Not entirely sure without being able to recreate though. Can you run an `explain plan`? Is `dat_results_ext` a table or a view, and what indexes are there?

Comment: Its a view... And having checked the explain plan - you are right!! Its pushing the to_date up into the dat_results_ext query, which is resulting in a full table scan.

Comment: @AndyMorton sometimes the optimize is too smart for its own good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimizer can rewrite your query before trying to find the best execution plan. In your case since you have no hints that would prevent the optimizer from doing this, it will probably [unnest your subquery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries008.htm#SQLRF52358) and rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dat_results_ext
 WHERE item_name = 'CALLBACKDATE'
   AND to_date(response, 'DD/MM/YYYY') > sysdate
```

You don't have control over the order of evaluation of the statements in the WHERE clause, so Oracle probably evaluated the `to_date` function first on a row that is not convertible to a date, hence the error.

I see two options to force Oracle to evaluate the statements in the order you want:

1. Use rownum. Rownum will materialize the subquery, preventing Oracle from merging it with the outer query:

   ```
   SELECT visit_id, to_date(response, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS convertedDate
     FROM (SELECT r.*, 
                  rownum /* will materialize the subquery */
             FROM dat_results_ext r
            WHERE item_name = 'CALLBACKDATE')
    WHERE to_date(response, 'DD/MM/YYYY') > sysdate
   ```
2. Use the [`NO_MERGE` hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50507):

   ```
   SELECT visit_id, to_date(response, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS convertedDate
     FROM (SELECT /*+ NO_MERGE */ *
             FROM dat_results_ext
            WHERE item_name = 'CALLBACKDATE')
    WHERE to_date(response, 'DD/MM/YYYY') > sysdate
   ```

Comment: Victory Secured! The Oracle optimiser seems to be a law unto itself, but adding the rownum forced it! Thanks Vincent

Answer (score 0):

The TO_DATE clause has to be evaluated before the truth of the WHERE clause can be determined. If you have values of response that can't be evaluated in the TO_DATE function, you'll see the error.

Comment: DCookie, the 'select * from dat_results_ext....' query only returns one row, with that one row having '28/09/2012' in the response field. I would have thought that the where clause for the main query would only impact on the results coming out of the subquery, which only returns one row??

Comment: There's a simple way to test this. Build a table without any bad data and try it.  You can't count on how Oracle evaluates this. It may decide to merge the two queries into a single one, where both WHERE clauses are evaluated at the same time. You might be able to use hints to get around it, but I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

To be very precise, this is caused because some value of `response` do not match the format mask of `DD/MM/YYYY`. For example, if your session is set to default date format of `DD-MON-YY`, execute the following and you will receive the error message:-

```
select to_date('17/SEP/2012','DD/MM/YYYY') from dual;
ERROR:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Since you passed a character in the month field and Oracle expects a number.