# ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected for a simple select query

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01858

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
>
> 1858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
>
> *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
>               incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
>               required by the format model.
>
> *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
>               elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

I understand why this error may occur but why does it show up when I do a simple select * query?

My query is as simple as this,

```
select * from myView;
```

Other observations are, the query works perfectly fine in the java application. Both the Java application and my Oracle client uses the same JDBC String, Username & Password.

What could be it? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is mytable perhaps a view?

Comment: It actually is. Does it make a difference? I edited my sample query.

Comment: Well, if the underlying query fails and you create a view based on that query... it will fail too. I suggest you run the query the view is based on, then strip out column by column until you hit the one that is causing the issue. If it is unclear why it is causing the problem you can share the query here and someone will respond.

Comment: Thank you. As already mentioned in my post, the query works fine inside the Java application. There was some data incorrect issues reported, so to debug I fired up a select (*) and I had this error code. And I tried a select *, same error. I looked at the Java application and it still serves data, so the query works there.

Comment: As you say your view works in one session (Java) and not the other, the view probably relies on some session settings, which it shouldn't . Something like `WHERE mydate > TO_DATE('FEB 03, 2000')` instead of `WHERE mydate > DATE '2000-02-03'`.

Comment: a "select *" will look at all the columns. It is up to you to debug this, you have the view, the table and the data. Instead of doing ```SELECT *``` look at the view the query is based on and run it column by column, one column at a time. That will allow you to pinpoint the culprit column in the view.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, people. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In past there was something very similar we encountered, and it wasn't a bad data really.
Try once using hint - `NO_MERGE` and it might work.

```
select /*+ NO_MERGE */ * from myview;
```

Let me know if that works.

Found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12460756/3961706) which helped me back then.